# Blazor server app Authorization Handler to query database

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor server app.  Users can create entries that then need to be approved by the users manager or the managers manager (we have a fat hierarchy structure).   The reporting structure is maintained in a database.  The app is using windows authentication (Negotiate).

Users should only be able to view entries if they created the entry or if they are a manager or manager's manager of the user that created the entry.

I was thinking about creating an AuthorizationHandler to do this. So I created a custom handler that can query the database, and then use that handler in a policy, then apply the policy to my page.  It's basically a generalized AuthorizationHandler which allows you to define a function in the app, associated to the policy, that the handler calls, and the function can do anything it needs to do.

I am having two issues.

1. Sometimes my handler gets called multiple times, which would be inefficient if it has to query the database.
2. I don't know how to retrieve route parameters from the request, from within the handlers function.  It always returns null.

Here's my simplified code that defines the authorization handler:

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows "dynamic" policies to be defined in the application that can call a function within the app
/// </summary>
public class DynamicAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<DynamicAuthorizationRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public DynamicAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;            
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, DynamicAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        DynamicPolicyArgs args = new DynamicPolicyArgs()
        {
            PolicyDescription = requirement.Description,
            PolicyName = requirement.PolicyName,
            AuthorizationHandlerContext = context,
            HttpContext = contextAccessor
        };

        //Call the function delegate to determine if the user is authorized
        var isAuthorized = await requirement.OnAuthorizeAsync(args);
        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}

public class DynamicAuthorizationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public DynamicAuthorizationRequirement(string policyName, string policyDescription, Func<DynamicPolicyArgs, Task<bool>> funcAuthorize)
    {       
        PolicyName = policyName;
        Description = policyDescription;
        OnAuthorizeAsync = funcAuthorize;
    }

    public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Func<DynamicPolicyArgs, Task<bool>> OnAuthorizeAsync { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }
}

public class DynamicPolicyArgs
{
    public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    public string PolicyDescription { get; set; }
    public AuthorizationHandlerContext AuthorizationHandlerContext { get; set; }
    public IHttpContextAccessor HttpContext { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Extensions for adding dynamic policies
/// </summary>
public static class DynamicAuthorizationHandlerExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add a policy with a matching function to execute which will evaluate the policy
    /// </summary>
    public static AuthorizationOptions AddDynamicPolicy(this AuthorizationOptions options, 
        string policyName, 
        string policyDescription,
        Func<DynamicPolicyArgs, Task<bool>> funcAuthorize, Action<string, AuthorizationPolicyBuilder> configure)
    {
        //Create policy
        AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
        builder.Requirements.Add(new DynamicAuthorizationRequirement(policyName, policyDescription, funcAuthorize));

        if (configure != null)
        {
            configure(policyName, builder);
        }
        var policy = builder.Build();
        options.AddPolicy(policyName, policy);

        return options;
    }

}
```

Then I add the policy in my application:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddDynamicPolicy("AllowOnlyCreatorOrApprover", "Allows only the creator or an approver to view the page", AuthorizeClaimCreatorOrApproverAsync);
});

private Task<bool> AuthorizeClaimCreatorOrApproverAsync(DynamicPolicyArgs args)
{
    bool result = false;
    //Get route param...
    var id = args.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("ID");
    if (id != null)
    {
        //Query database...
    }
    
    return Task.FromResult<bool>(result);
}
```

Now, I enforce the policy on my page:

```
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "AllowOnlyCreatorOrApprover")]
```

Comment: _"Sometimes my handler gets called multiple times, which would be inefficient if it has to query the database."_ - In-memory caching of permissions (with a short cache eviction timeout, say, 30 seconds?) should help eliminate that problem - and having a short timeout means you won't need to worry about cache-invalidation and revocation.

Comment: _"I don't know how to retrieve route parameters from the request, from within the handlers function. It always returns null."_ - Unfortunately this is because ASP.NET Core performs the Request Authorization step _before_ it performs request parameter binding (for security reasons: only bind trusted values!) - in a recent project of mine I worked-around this by extracting the parsed (but not bound) request values from Route-Data (though this was for MVC, not Blazor - but I assume the technique is the same).

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `IHttpContextAccessor`, and set the `Resource` attribute to use the `HttpContext`.

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <!-- The 'Resource' property will be used in 'HasAppHandler' to obtain the 'app' route parameter -->
        <!-- If we implement new policies to protect resources, we should protect them with resource based uri and compare them with the user's claims. -->
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" Resource="@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layouts.MainLayout)">
            <!-- When visiting a page that requires authorization, but the user isn't authorized, redirect to the login page -->
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectToLogin/>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
    </Found>
</Router>
```

Then you can access it as follows:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasAppRoleRequirement requirement)
{
    if (context.Resource is not HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But as people pointed out, do not trust the values alone. Use claims, sanitization and what not.